# Is Time Constrained acceptable?

Tags: grammar, adjectives, compound-words

I've composed a sentence but I'm not sure if it's acceptable.

> This is a time constrained campaign.

I want to make the *time constraint* sound like an adjective but I don't know how. I just ended up rephrasing it but I still want to know about my given sentence.

Thank you.

Comment: [smallbusiness](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/difference-between-timeconstrained-resourceconstrained-36487.html) are happy with it, it has quite a few tokens on the internet, and it seems clear enough. But there seems to be a preference for a hyphen.

Comment: Typo: you missed the 'a' ...'This is a time-constrained campaign' looks fine to me, with- or sans-hyphen.

Answer (score 1):

Most people would be unable to explain why but they'd still feel uncomfortable with your original sentence… which is why you asked, isn't it? Your aim is to combine *time* and *constrained* into a single term describing the campaign, is it not? Then please, use a hyphen to join them… Remembering that most native speakers wouldn’t follow that if their lives depended on it, still that’s termed *adjectival hyphenation*.